# Is it possible for 8 different numbers to exist that when combined form unique results?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, coloring

I am wrestling with a question relating to colors, specifically hexadecimal color codes. A hexadecimal color code is represented in three parts, Red, Green, and Blue, all ranging from 0-255. These three numbers combine to represent a color.

My question is, is it possible for eight different colors to exist that, when combined (through a blending function defined below,) with 1-7 of the other colors, results in a unique color that can not be achieved from combining any other combination of the eight colors. Additionally, the resultant color may not be one of the original eight colors.

The blending occurs with colors sorted from darkest to lightest (smallest to largest sum of each Red, Green, and Blue values,) entered into a blending function $B$ which averages the Red, Green, and Blue values separately. The colors are blended with each other starting with the two darkest, then that resultant is blended with the next darkest, etc until only one color remains.

Any amount of colors can be blended from 2-8 of the eight colors. This will allow a total of 256 resultant colors if you permit the original colors to be a resultant color as well.

**Please provide a proof proving this is possible or impossible.**

Additionally, your answer is given extra consideration if you prove a way to pick colors that, when blended, provide the most diverse resultant colors (most differing in distance from each other.)

*Side note: I am typing this on mobile, so I cannot read the descriptions of the tags I have chosen. If there are more appropriate tags, feel free to apply them or ask me to.*

Comment: Do you mean: there are 2 sets of 8 colors, blend the second and get all possible colors; is there a newly created color from the second set that cannot be created by blending the colors in first set?

Comment: There is a single set of eight colors that blend in 256 combinations which must create 256 unique colors

Comment: Do you ask if there exists a set of 8 colors s.t. you can belnd into 256 different combinations?

Comment: Yes, essentially.